# Inverse Kinetic constraint is behaving wildly

Tags: rigging

[image]I'm following the instruction from Introducing characters animation from Tony Mullen and I just rigged my first leg and it's behaving wildly. If I move my mouse just a little the leg goes off in a random direction. How can fix this? The target for the C_D_Leg bone(the one at an angle) is the disconnected bone in the lower right. And to apply the constraint I selected the target, shift selected the C_D_Leg and press shift+I.

[image]

Comment: Likely dependency loop.  What is the parent of C_D_Leg.001?  It cannot be a bone involved in the IK.

Comment: You're right! I cleared the parent and parented C_D_LEg.001 to root and now it works! Thanks!